# WiX Setup project referencing two Wixlib having same File/@Id

Tags: wix, wixlib

I am new to WiX, but need a complicated scenario! 
I manage a modular web application containing multiple WCF Library (i.e. module), and need to put every module as a feature in the final setup.

So I managed a `WiX Setup Library` for every module which genrates `.wixlib` files, and a single `WiX Setup` who references the `.wixlib` projects, and also will be a one-to-one relation between modules (i.e. `.wixlib`) and features in the final setup.

The problem arises when there is same files shared among `.wixlib`s, due to similar `File/@Id` and `Componend/@Id` which will be there for those shared files.

P.S: I have used [WaX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.Wax) as engine to build `.wxs` files, which simply uses file name as `File/@Id` and `Component/@Id` in the `.wxs` files.

I beleive there could be two possible workarounds (I could achevei non of them!)

1. Some way to force [WaX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.Wax) generate randome `File/@Id` and `Component/@Id` for every file.
2. The could be a way in `Lit.exe` (who builds `.wixlib`) to append a random id to `File/@Id` and `Component/@Id` while compiling and generating final `.wixlib` files.

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can look into using heat.exe it will generate unique component and file Ids if you pass in the right command line args. Seems like heat.exe does the same thing as WaX but is a command line tool.

Comment: Yep. I also decided to go for heat.exe. Looks that WaX has very limited capabilities right now.

Comment: And finally i decided to put away WIX for now. probably in future they will provide better streamlined process.